# Asp.net access DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a Datalist in the page:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="98%" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="7" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:ShopLine id="ShopLine1" runat="server" DataItem='<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
                                        ShopListLineId='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShopListLineID") %>'
                                        OnDataUpdated="ShopLine1_DataUpdated">
        </uc1:ShopLine>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorStyle Width="1px" />
   <ItemStyle CssClass="listItem1" />
</asp:DataList>
```

Shopline is an ascx file.

I was trying to use following code to access each item in the datalist:

```
 foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
             {
                 string productId = DataBinder.Eval(dli.DataItem, "ProductID").ToString();
                 TextBox tb = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("QtyTextBox");
             }
```

and the dli.Dataitem is null and textbox is null as well, but the datalist acturally display items and  shopline.ascs does have a TeXtBox id is "QtyTextBox".

Can anyone give me an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Where you have this code?

Comment: Which even are u placing this code? before checking dli.DataItem, check what and how many items are present in DataList1.Items by using a quick watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the item you're looking at is an actual DataItem.  Use this code inside your for loop to check that you're looking at an actual item (and not a footer / header / etc):

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{

}
```

Also, I think you need to get your UserControl first.  Then you can find things inside it.

Your final product would be something like this:

```
foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        string productId = DataBinder.Eval(dli.DataItem, "ProductID").ToString();

        // Find the UserControl that's in this DataListItem
        ShopLine myShopLine = (ShopLine)dli.Findcontrol("ShopLine1");
        //Then extract the information you need from it
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)myShopLine.FindControl("QtyTextBox");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I found it I need to get the UserControl First, Thanks for that

Comment: @simoncat Excellent!  I'm glad I could help.  FYI - if this answer solved your problem, you can "accept it" using the checkmark box.  See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for details.